# Property lat must be a float displaying in my dashboard

Tags: python, google-app-engine, floating-point, cron

I have created a Google AppEngine Project which takes in a .txt file, finds locations within the file and uses Yahoo Placemaker to plot a maker on the map to represent the .txt file.
The project works fine when I run in on my localhost but when I try and upload it to appspot I get an error:

> BadValueError: Property lat must be a float

My main.py looks like this:

```
class Story(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty()
    loc_name = db.StringProperty()
    title = db.StringProperty()
    lat = db.FloatProperty()
    long = db.FloatProperty()
    link = db.StringProperty()

class MyStories(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        temp = db.Query(Story)
        temp = temp.count()


        story_set = Story.all()

        template_values = {
            'storyTemp': story_set
        }

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

class place(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        path = '/Users/kimmasterson/storing/txtFiles'

           try:
            for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.txt')):
                    #print infile
                    f = open(infile, 'r')
                    data = f.read()
                    newfile = infile.replace('.txt', '')
                    newfile = newfile.replace('/Users/kimmasterson/storing/txtFiles/', '')
                    #print newfile
                    storyname = 'http://www.independent.ie/national-news/' + newfile
                    #print storyname
                    #print newfile
                    #logging.info(data)
                    p = placemaker('HSnG9pPV34EUBcexz.tDYuSrZ8Hnp.LowswI7TxreF8sXrdpVyVIKB4uPGXBYOA9VjjF1Ca42ipd_KhdJsKYjI5cXRo0eJM-')
                    print p.find_places(data)
                    for place in p.places:
                        splitted = place.name.split()
                        for word in splitted:
                            temp = db.Query(Story)
                            temp = temp.filter("link = ", storyname)
                            results = temp.fetch(limit=1)
                            if len(results) >0:
                                break
                            elif 'IE' in word:
                                print temp
                                print 'success'
                                story = Story(name=newfile, lat=place.centroid.latitude, long=place.centroid.longitude, link=storyname, loc_name = place.name, title = newfile).put()
        except:
            print 'error'
            logging.info('BIG FAT ERROR')

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MyStories), ('/place', place)],
                                         debug=True)

    wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

My cron.yaml:

```
cron:
- description: running place

  url: /place

  schedule: every day 10:00
```

For some reason it adds the places and links the file to the map on my localhost.  Any ideas how the same code in both places can work in one and not in the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer is that `lat` (which you're getting from `place.centroid.latitude`) isn't a float. Try logging `type(place.centroid.latitude)` to see what type it is - my guess would be that it's a string, and you'll need to call `float()` on it to parse it.

As @Thomas points out, you obviously can't refer to a file on your local machine and expect it to work once uploaded to App Engine. Instead, put your static data inside your app's root directory (or a subdirectory), and open it with a relative path. The easiest and most robust way to do that is like this:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'path/to/your/file')
```

Comment: The error is gone but still there is no markers coming up on my map.  I've added this line of code to my main.py:   path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'/Users/kimmasterson/storing/txtFiles') as you recommended is there somewhere in main.py that it should be placed i.e: at the top?

Comment: @jenniem001 You're still trying to reference a file on your hard drive from your app. `/Users/kimmasterson` is not going to exist on the production server. You need to put the file in the same directory as your app.yaml, then just use 'txtFiles' as the path in the above.

Comment: I have changed all my paths to read: 
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '/storing/txtFiles')
I have no no error logs and my cron is running successfully.  But I still have no markers any ideas?  Am I doing something wrong?  This is my log:
"This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application."

But I have waited and there are no markers on my map.

Answer (score 2):

1. The really obvious: `path = '/Users/kimmasterson/storing/txtFiles'` - I hope you're not uploading exactly that to Appengine, because obviously that's not going to work on a remote server.
2. If you print out some details about `place`, what do you get just before the error?

**EDIT:**

Looking at what you're trying to do, I don't think you actually need to upload text files. You're trying to get places from stories on the independent.ie website, right? You can just pass a URL to placemaker:

```
p.find_places("http://www.independent.ie/national-news/patient-too-large-for-ambulance-2619414.html")
```

Yahoo will get the page from independent.ie directly, rather than sending it from your application.

Comment: If i look at localhost:8080/place I get stuff like this: "[<Placemaker Place: 'Abbeyfeale, Limerick, IE'>, <Placemaker Place: 'Churchtown, Cork, IE'>, <Placemaker Place: 'Mallow, Cork, IE'>, <Placemaker Place: 'Cork, IE'>, <Placemaker Place: 'Limerick, IE'>]" But there is nothing in place on appspot. Because my cron says it is successfull but when I click logs it has that error.

Comment: Is there a way of putting my .txt files on appEngine so it can access them?!

Comment: @jenniem001: I believe you can upload them if you configure a static folder in `app.yaml`. I don't know what the size limits for files are. Or you could use the URL fetch service to grab the files directly from the independent.ie website. Or you could process them on your computer, and produce a CSV file which you feed into Appengine's bulk data uploader.

Comment: Configuring a static folder is the opposite of what you want to do: Static files are not accessible by apps directly. Instead, just upload the file within your app and access it via a relative path.

Comment: @jenniem001: Actually, I don't think you need to upload the text files at all. I've updated my answer with what should be an easier way to do it.

Comment: Thats great I didn't realise I could do that.  But this is only a small part of my task.  The reason I have text files is because they all get classified as crime/not-crime.

Comment: @jenniem001: OK, cool. Is that going to be automatic? Is the plan for it to happen on the appengine server, or are you going to classify them on your computer and upload the data?